# Python Operations (Intersection, Union, Duplicate) with nested Lists/Tuples possible?

Tags: python, list, nested

Case:

```
a = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(1,6),(1,7)]
b = [(5,2),(6,3),(4,5),(6,8),(1,9)]
```

How can i remove duplicates by first tuple item?

Result for a would be:

```
[(1,2),(2,3),(4,5)]
```

Result for b would be:

```
[(5,2),(6,3),(4,5),(1,9)]
```

How can i merge both without duplicates?:
Result would be:

```
[(1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(5,2),(6,3)]
```

How can i get the intersection of both?:
Result would be:

```
[(1,2),(4,5)]
```

Is this in an easy way possible?

Best Regards
Chris

Comment: Why is (1, 2) in the intersection? Do we say that x is an element of the intersection of A and B if both A and B have an element with the same "key" (first element of the pair) as x? And if so, which second element do we take?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order

Comment: @CalebLevine Because i need the Intersection by the first Element of every tuple item. So in a and b start two tuples with 1 ( (1,9) in a and (1,2) in b). Intersection would be (1,9) or (1,2) ... (4,5) too!

Comment: What is the expected value for intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sets:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> s1 = [x for x in a if x[0] not in seen and not seen.add(x[0])]
>>> seen = set()
>>> s2 = [x for x in b if x[0] not in seen and not seen.add(x[0])]
>>> s1
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
>>> s2
[(5, 2), (6, 3), (4, 5), (1, 9)]
```

Union:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x for x in chain(s1,s2) if x[0] not in seen and not seen.add(x[0])]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (5, 2), (6, 3)]
```

Intersection:

```
>>> se1 = set(x[0] for x in s1)
>>> se2 = set(x[0] for x in s2)
>>> inter = se1 & se2
>>> inter
set([1, 4])
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x for x in chain(s1,s2) if x[0] in inter and x[0] not in seen
                                                          and not seen.add(x[0])]
[(1, 2), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first one is exactly what i want. The Union and Intersection should be referenced to first item of the Tuple too (how in the first example).The Intersection result of duplicates free a and b should be: [(1,2), (1,9)]. For Union the same.

Comment: @user2543694 intersection should be `[(1,2),(4,5)]`, as per what you posted in question body.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple Python3 example for removing duplicates. Another contributor covered the other two.

```
ixs = {tup[0]:i for i, tup in list(enumerate(a))[::-1]}
[a[i] for i in sorted(ixs.values())]
```

Comment: Why do you need `enumerate` and `[::-1]` - why not just `reversed(a)` and use `None` as a key for all (it's not required for anything useful). Anyway - this won't end up with the same order output as shown by the OPs example...